# Django & nginx & uwsgi can not connect

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

it's my nginx.conf

```
# nginx.conf
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to 
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/user/djangosite/project/project.sock;
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name .example.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/user/djangosite/project/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/user/djangosite/project/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/user/djangosite/project/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
 }
```

and it's my uwsgi.ini

```
# introduction_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /home/user/djangosite/project
# Django's wsgi file
module          = introduction.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /home/user/djangosite/django_virtual

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /home/user/djangosite/project/project.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
# chmod-socket    = 664
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

it's my uwsgi log

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14 (64bit) on [Mon Mar 27 23:34:22 2017] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 16 March 2017 00:34:31
os: Linux-4.8.0-41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 17:11:16 UTC 2017
nodename: user-VirtualBox
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /home/user/djangosite/project
detected binary path: /home/user/djangosite/django_virtual/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/user/djangosite/project
your processes number limit is 7833
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/user/djangosite/project/project.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.6.0 (default, Mar 16 2017, 00:24:05)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1efd260
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 800448 bytes (781 KB) for 10 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x1efd260 pid: 12449 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 12449)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 12451, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 12452, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 12453, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 12454, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 12455, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 12456, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 12457, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 12458, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 9 (pid: 12459, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 10 (pid: 12460, cores: 1)
SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
worker 2 buried after 1 seconds
worker 3 buried after 1 seconds
worker 4 buried after 1 seconds
worker 5 buried after 1 seconds
worker 6 buried after 1 seconds
worker 7 buried after 1 seconds
worker 8 buried after 1 seconds
worker 9 buried after 1 seconds
worker 10 buried after 1 seconds
```

When I execute "uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini", I cann't connect to the correct page.
It showed ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
I don't know how to figure out this problem, please help me

Comment: check file permissions on the socket file; or try running uwsgi in network mode and connect to it via localhost:port to see if it is working fine.

Comment: @warath-coder 
The permission of socket is mine not root's, but it still don't work correctly.